# using global controls in different methods

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to declare a global control (checkboxlist) variable and populate in one methode and check which one are selected in another method

```
    public CheckBoxList chklExtraDrink ;


 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     chklExtraDrink = new CheckBoxList();

}
    //this function will fill the checkboxlist
    public void fillupCheckboxlist(GridViewRow row)
{
  chklExtraDrink.RepeatColumns = 3;
      Accordion accorExtra = (row.FindControl("accorExtra") as Accordion);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string cmdstr = "select p.name + ' (€' + cast(pp.value as varchar) + ')' as name, (CAST(p.product_id as varchar) + ',' + CAST(pp.price_id as varchar))as valueF from product p, price_product pp  WHERE p.product_id = pp.product_id and p.main_product_id = @mainProductId";
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdstr, new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db_pizzaConnectionString"].ConnectionString));
    adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mainProductId", 26);
    adp.Fill(ds);
    chklExtraDrink.DataSource = ds;
    chklExtraDrink.DataTextField = "name";
    chklExtraDrink.DataValueField = "valueF";
    chklExtraDrink.DataBind();

    AccordionPane ap1 = new AccordionPane();
    ap1.HeaderContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("text"));
    ap1.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(chklExtraDrink);

    accorExtra.Panes.Add(ap1);

}
   //this function will eventually check all selected items
   public void btnOkay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


foreach (ListItem item in chklExtraDrink.Items)
        if (item.Selected) values.Add(new Order(item.Value.Split(',')[0], item.Value.Split(',')[1], emptyList, 1));
    }
```

with this code, i am getting no values back from the checkboxlist.

Comment: When the button is clicked, the page is reloaded and the Page_Load event is executed again, creating a new empty CheckBoxList before btnOkay_Click() is executed.

Comment: I tried to use the page_init method but also same result.

Answer (score -1):

Can you show the code with the event handler? Typically, the btnClick will have handling code inside. You can use the Events view of the Properties window to see the events and select the events you want to handle.

Getting the button click is just the first step. You need to assign a handler and write a handler method to be called when the event triggers it.

EDIT:
Links are short lived, but while it lasts, here is the Microsoft doco:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa984320%28v=vs.94%29

A quick example is below:

```
namespace StackOverflow
{
    public partial class UserForm : Form      
    {
        public UserForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void clbCheckedListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // code here or call to generic handler
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I can use that part of code. I am not using winform, but pages. that click event is called in aspx page. Where do I need to initialize this control?